# How to use new wp_query instance in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I use new wp_query instance in the template file in Wordpress.

Tried

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you missed the_post() in the loop.

correct code

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post(); 
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```